# How to methodically join two lists?

Tags: python, list

So basically I have two lists in python, I want to join them together but in a certain way. I want them to be intertwined, I guess. Here’s an example.

```
List_a = [1, 2, 3]

List_b = [4, 5, 6]

Joined_Lists = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

I want the joined list to be the lists combined together, but by inserting an item from list b every other one. I hope I explained this somewhat decent, lol.

Comment: [x for sublist in zip(List_a, List_b) for x in sublist]

Comment: @DarrylG Why not post that as an answer (maybe accompanied by the equivalent explicit loops by way of explanation)? - though you might want a different variable name than `sublist` given that they are actually tuples

Comment: It can be done by calling the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Comment: @alaniwi--thanks, but I try to make a rule to only comment when I only spend a minute on a response.  If I had spent more than time I probably would have thought of a better variable name than sublist as you suggested :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a comprehension:

```
def interleave(*iterables):
    return [x for y in zip(*iterables) for x in y]
```

Then

```
>>> interleave([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
>>> interleave([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,10])
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

Note that this interleaves until the **first** iterable is exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with slice assignment, assuming the lists are either equal length, or `a` is 1 element longer than `b`:

```py
def alternating(a, b):
    n = len(a) + len(b)
    out = [None] * n
    out[::2] = a
    out[1::2] = b
    return out
```

Examples:

```py
>>> alternating([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
>>> alternating([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7])
[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The convenient way to do it is clearly the `[x for sublist in zip(List_a, List_b) for x in sublist]` originally mentioned by DarrylG (although possibly with a different variable name, as `zip` yields tuples rather than lists). But more for sake of curiosity than anything, here is an alternative:

```
import itertools

def intertwine(*lists):
    return list(next(i) for i in itertools.cycle(iter(x) for x in lists))
```

The unusual thing about this example is that the `for i in itertools.cycle(...)` is an infinite loop, but the `next(i)` can raise `StopIteration` when one of the iterators which it yields is exhausted, and then the overall iterator (argument to `list`) will treat it in the same way as if the `for i in ...` loop had done the same.

So it gives:

```
>>> intertwine([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Note that the superficially equivalent list comprehension:

```
[next(i) for i in itertools.cycle(iter(x) for x in lists)]
```

would **not** work - an explicit `StopIteration` will be raised in the user code.

Answer (score 0):

just to add to the existing (better) solutions, noting that this is essentially a transpose operation

```
> np.array(List_a+List_b).reshape(2,3).transpose().reshape(1,6)

array([[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]])
```